# Android - Limiting ViewPager fragments number

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I've created a `Fragment` for every screen of my activity, I want to use one activity and switch screens using fragments.

I need the left/right swipe functionality so I'm trying to use one `ViewPager` to handle all my screens.

In most app scenarios only a few `Fragments` should be available at any point, for example, the first screen the user should get is the Login fragment which should not allow switching to the next Fragment using a swiping forward. And after a successful login the user should not be able to go back to the login screen by swiping backwards.

Is there a recommended way to implement that?

Comment: For login you can use separate fragment once login succes you can go to ViewPager.  ViewPager contains your remaining fragments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem of your design is that you are trying to put a variety of different functionalities into one `Activity`.

I'll give you an example. Say you have an RSS reader which requires users to login in order to e.g. sync liked news. If you try to squeeze it into one `Activity` you will end up with monster-class responsible for loading data, displaying it, logging in, creating an account, handling sign-in/sign-up errors etc.

Even if you use `Fragments` you will still have to handle numerous actions from your `Activity`

It is better to distribute the responsibilities between different `Activities`, each handling different functionalities e. g. `NewsActivity` to handle the RSS news feed, and `LoginActivity` to handle authentication. Use `Fragments` to distinguish different parts of user interface of the given functionality rather than functionality itself.

Please [read more](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) about organizing `Activities`.